# Delete shapefile object

Tags: qgis

I have a shapefile layer which comprises of a series of lines which represent archaeological features. I cannot delete individual lines as the delete button is greyed out. Is there a way for me to delete an individual object as I note the button is greyed out on other layers (polygons & dots). Incidentally, cut, copy and paste buttons are also greyed out.I'm using QGIS version 2.6 on aMac running Yosemite.

Comment: sounds like there is some kind of lock on the data - is it being used / open in another application?

Comment: have you toggled edit mode?

Comment: Would be important to know if Toggle Mode can be switched on. Try to right click on shapefile and "Save as" as a new shapefile and reload the new one, this sometimes helps.

Comment: Thank you to those who responded to my question. Yes toggle editing is on and I've tried saving and reloading, and saving the layer as a different name and in a different location. I've even quit QGIS and reloaded and the delete button is still greyed out.Also the data is not being used by any other programs.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting lines from attribute tables is generally a bit tricky. There is a (not too elegant but working) way around it by using Excel and working on the DBF file that comes with the pile of files when saving as a shapefile in Excel. The DBF represents your attribute table. You can open it with Excel and delete the lines you want there. Then you will need to save it as csv file (Excel can't save DBF) and reload it into QGIS using `Add Delimited Text Layer`. If you want to work on it as a shapefile again, you will need to save it again as a shape file using `Save as`.
As said, not the most elegant way. A bit easier is using R if you can code in R. You can load and save DBF files in R using the "foreign" package.

Answer (score 0):

You can not edit shapefiles if you have set a filter on the file.

To avoid that, you need to store your data in a spatialite database.